# Pandas Dataframe merge to get only non-existing records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Okay.. so I'm trying to merge two dataframes to only get the records from dataframe1 (df) that doesn't already exist in dataframe2 (df_existing)

columns in both dataframes:
symbolid
timeframeid
datetime
open
high
low
close
volume

Code snippet that as far as I know used to work fine:

```
df2 = df.merge(df_existing,
                        on = ['symbolid', 'timeframeid', 'datetime'],
                        how = 'left',
                        indicator = True).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop(columns = '_merge')
```

The result now is showing all the non-join columns duplicated with suffixes _x and _y according to what df they originate from.

The desired outcome is the same columns as in the original dataframes but with the duplicate rows based on symbolid, timeframeid and datetime removed.

Comment: Please provide dataframe constructors of your inputs for reproducibility and the matching expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to align two DataFrames, you can avoid suffixes by just slicing the merging columns:

```
cols = ['symbolid', 'timeframeid', 'datetime']

df2 = (df.merge(df_existing[cols],
                on=cols, how='left',
                indicator=True)
         .query('_merge == "left_only"')
         .drop(columns = '_merge')
       )
```

Alternative with [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter and drop in a single step:

```
cols = ['symbolid', 'timeframeid', 'datetime']

df2 = (df.merge(df_existing[cols],
                on=cols, how='left',
                indicator=True)
         .loc[lambda d: d.pop('_merge').eq('left_only')
     )
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks for the perfect answer and helping me out when my mind obv went blank for a moment.